# Application of Derivatives and analysis of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$F(x)=(f(x))^{2}+\left(f^{\prime}(x)\right)^{2},\,F(0)=7,$ where $f(x)$ is thrice differentiable function such that $|f(x) |\leq 1\, \forall x \in[-1,1],$ then prove the followings.

1. There is at least one point in each of the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ where $\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right| \leq 2$.
2. There is at least one point in each of the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ where $F(x) \leq 5$.
3. There exits at least one maxima of $F(x)$ in $(-1,1)$.
4. For some $c \in(-1,1), F(c) \geq 7, F^{\prime}(c)=0$ and $F^{\prime \prime}(c) \leq 0$

---

I tried writing the expression for $f'(x)$ using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem.
$$|f'(x)|=|f(1) - f(0)|,\;\text{ for at least one}\; x ∈ (0,1)$$ $$|f'(x)|≤ 2 $$

Similar things can be proven for $x ∈ (-1,0)$.
Hence for at least one $x$ in each of the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ we have $F(x)≤5$.

I am not able to prove $3$ and $4$ statement in the question. Please help me.

Comment: Tyset the mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image (this time I've done for you). [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).